# rxJS - what is come instead of 'Promise.done'

Tags: typescript, rxjs

In rxjs, when I call http-get, I accept observable type, instead of Promise type of simple javascript.

Now I search after what come instead of promise.done?

I saw that people use Observale.map, but I not need map - map is for multiple http callings.

What comes before?

Comment: Once way is just call `.toPromise()` on your observable and use the functions you already know. You might have to use `import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';`

Comment: `.subscribe(...)` is usually the end of the chain. See http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/tutorial.html.

Comment: Use `.subscribe()` on your `Observable`, or `.toPromise()` but you'll have to get used to using `.then()` as there's no `.done()` on a standard `Promise`. I guess you're used to the broken `jQuery` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Simply subscribe to the request method (such as get/post/etc). You don't need to use toPromise(), and I would recommend against it as Angular works very nicely with Observables and they are much more powerful than Promises.

```
// Make the HTTP request:
this.http.get('/api/items').subscribe(data => {
  // Handle the result from the response.
  this.results = data;
});
```

https://angular.io/guide/http

Don't worry about unsubscribing from these Observables as they call the .complete() method on the observer and finish.

It's worth noting that all Observables returned from HttpClient are cold and no requests will be made until you .subscribe() to them.

I think you might be confusing map with switchMap as well, map is for transforming the emitted items within the stream, switchMap is commonly used for chaining observables nicely.
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html